# ObjectMapper Custom serializer for serializing a List<User> to User object

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, fasterxml

I've below Group and User Model objects

```
 public class Group {
            List<User> user;
        }
    
        public class User {
            String title;
        }
```

I'm using Jackson to serialize this Group Object. I want to return  single User object in the response instead of returning `List<User>` array. Basically I want to convert `List<User>` to User to send User as an object in the json response instead of list.   I can not use @Jsonserelize annotation serialize the List data to object due to modal objects are generated from external schema.

I know that I can use below annotation to apply converter but unfortunately in my case, modal classes are generated from external schema and I do not have option to add below annotation.

```
@JsonSerialize(converter = ListUserConverter.class)
List<User> user;
```

I thought I could add something like below however getting compile time and looks like not supported for List of specific type.

```
 simpleModule.addSerializer(List<User>.class, new StdDelegatingSerializer(new ListUserConverter()));

public class ListUserConverter extends StdConverter<List<User>, User> {
    @Override
    public User convert(List<User> users) {
        return users.get(0);
    }
}
```

Is there any another way to apply custom converter specific List to convert list to object?

How do I serialize only  List to User (get first object from list) with out annotation usage?

Comment: If you are using the `@JsonSerialize` annotation you don't have to add the serializer within `simpleModule.addSerializer()`. Could you try removing/commenting the annotation and checking result?

Comment: modal classes are from external library , I will not be able to modify the classes to add @JsonSerialize annotation, Is there any alternative way we can implement the solution.

Comment: Sorry, I missed some of your thoughts in the question. So you can't change both the controller that returns the data and the object?

Comment: I can change the controller but response pojo class that I can not change due to external dependencies.

Comment: But you can create another class as `Group` without `List<User>` and use it instead of the original one in the controller. It seems to be easy if the `Group` class contains only that list.

Comment: I just gave example , but response pojo class is very huge and it contains number complex attributes.